# validating input fields with javascript onsubmit

Tags: javascript

```
<input style="position:relative;" type="text" name="posted_settings[pprice]" value=""   />


<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckOrderForm(frm){
if(frm.elements["pprice"]'.value==""){
    alert("Please enter price");
    frm.elements["pprice"].focus();
    return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>
```

Code above only work when name="pprice". How to make the code to work to perform the check on posted_settings[pprice]?

Answer (score 0):

```
frm.elements["posted_settings\[pprice\]"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
frm.elements["posted_settings[pprice]"].value;
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/wTC6X/

**BTW:** There is syntax error in the posted code:

```
frm.elements["pprice"]'.value==""
```

The `'` after the last closing bracket creates and unterminated String literal.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess ... u wann't check the input of a form which contains several input field . 
from the code u wrote , did u meant to having a array of inputs ? when u do , just do as below :

```
 <input style="position:relative;" type="text" name="posted_settings[]" value=""   />
 <input style="position:relative;" type="text" name="posted_settings[]" value=""   />
 <input style="position:relative;" type="text" name="posted_settings[]" value=""   />
```

here are an array of input fields . let do the form check for them :

here is the example code : [link]http://jsbin.com/uhizoRA/90/edit

wish u good luck !